# How to control date format in all components from one in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have dates in all components.They are different formats to display. I want to control the date format in one typescript file.How can I do that?

app.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent {
Today=Date.now();

}
```

app.html

```
<div class="row">
<p>Current Date : {{Today | date}}</p>
 </div>
```

Advance Thanks guys..

Comment: Need more explanation like-> which format do you want? if you tried any code then what it giving back?

Comment: Create a directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

First you need to create a variable like this

```
public date_format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
```

Now in your html, specify the date format (using a variable),

```
<p>Current Date : {{Today | date: date_format}}</p>
```

Now you can store your date formats in an array like this;

```
formats = ['yyyy-MM-dd', 'dd-MM-yyyy']
```

and you can set any date format using a method like this

```
public changeFormat(formatId) {
   this.date_format = this.formats[formatId];
}
```

Comment: I place the first line in my app.ts and the second one in app.html what about the next two lines.

Comment: Next two lines should be in your app.ts file.

Comment: It show property doesn't exists in IntexComponent for date_format

Comment: It's works.But want to change all my dates format into the date_format which I choose

Comment: I have created a common service. Now you can inject that service every where